# drupal create a view to grab a nodes files by node id

Tags: drupal, file, view

Is there a way to create a view that takes an node id argument to get all the  files uploaded from that node. I have a page with cck multigroup with video title, video thumbnail, video file. In my node tpl I want to call a view to grab those files to create a playlist for a JW Player.

thanks

Comment: Are you using a CCK file field, or the Drupal core Upload/Attach files module?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal6 this is very straight forward. Using views arguments you can define the argument type and even set up a default argument. More detail can be found at the [Views Argument documentation page](http://drupal.org/node/54455). To have it only return the fields you want, is also very straight forward, under fields just choose the 3 fields you listed.